# Cómo agregar más items al menú principal

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Intenté bajar la parte desplegable a partir de donde termina el nav, lo logré, pero el resto de menús(menu2, menu3, menu4,...) se siguen corriendo hacia la derecha. En dónde está el error?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Quicksand';
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  display: block;
  padding: .2rem 0;
  color: #000;
  font-size: .875rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: rgb(235, 161, 24);
  text-decoration: none;
}

h4 {
  margin: .5rem 0 .75rem;
  padding-bottom: .5rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: normal;
}

h5 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  font-size: .875rem;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #2c3040;
}

nav::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.menu-submenu {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: .2rem;
  background: #2c304038;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-right: 30px;
}


/* .menu-submenu:hover {
  position: absolute;
} */

.subregion {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.menu-submenu:hover>li {
  display: block;
}

.menu-submenu:hover>li:first-child {
  border-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  color: rgb(235, 161, 24);
  cursor: default;
}


/* .menu-submenu:hover>li:first-child::after {
  content: '\f106';
} */

.menu-submenu:hover>li:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 0 .2rem .2rem;
}

.menu-submenu:hover+.temp::after {
  display: block;
}

.menu-submenu>li {
  background-color: #2c3040;
  display: none;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu-submenu>li:first-child {
  display: block;
  padding: .65rem;
  background: #2c3040;
  color: white;
  font-size: .875rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* .menu-submenu>li:first-child::after {
  content: '\f107';
  float: right;
} */

.menu-submenu>li:not(:first-child):hover {
  width: calc(960px - 6rem);
  border-right: none;
}

.menu-submenu>li:nth-child(2):hover::before {
  /* content: ''; */
  display: block;
  width: 12rem;
  height: 3rem;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

li h3 {
  width: 12rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding: .65rem .75rem;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-width: 1px 0;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  font-size: .875rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  cursor: default;
}

li:last-child:hover h3 {
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 .2rem;
}

li:hover h3 {
  width: calc(12rem + 1px);
  border-color: #bbb;
}

li:hover div {
  display: block;
}

li div {
  display: none;
  width: calc(850px - 6rem - 12rem);
  padding: 1rem 1.2rem;
  border-left: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-radius: 0 .2rem .2rem 0;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 12rem;
  z-index: 1;
}

.temp {
  display: flex;
  width: 72%;
  border-radius: .2rem;
  float: right;
  font-size: .875rem;
}

.temp::after {
  content: '';
  display: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.temp li {
  padding: .65rem 0;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  clear: both;
}

main p {
  margin: auto;
  color: #555;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

@media (max-width: 60rem) {
  .temp {
    width: 67%;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="menu-submenu">
    <li id>acerca de <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></li>
    <li>
      <h3>1</h3>
      <div class="subregion">
        <h4>1</h4>
        <ul>
          <li id="obando" style="float:right"><img src="https://es-static.z-dn.net/files/dcc/c91ce8b034207ce60fcf1b4f6d73ce73.jpg" alt="Mapa Nariño"></li>
          <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">d</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>2</h3>
      <div class="subregion">
        <h4> 2</h4>
        <ul>
     
          <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">d</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>3</h3>
      <div class="subregion">
        <h4>3</h4>
        <ul>
             <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">d</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
   

  </ul>

  <ul class="menu-submenu">
    <li id>Menu2</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="menu-submenu">
    <li id>Menu3</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="menu-submenu">
    <li id>Menu4</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="menu-submenu">
    <li id>Menu5</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Te dejo un ejemplo espero te sirva
https://codepen.io/connorbrassington/pen/raNrEW Saludos.

Comment: te recomiendo que revises [tour] y que cheques que respuestas se esperan [answer] pues una respuesta que solo es un enlace se considera de baja calidad, pues no solo a ti te debe servir si no a futuros usuarios, lo cual se hace dificil si en un momento dado ese link deja de funcionar

Comment: Gracias, intenté hacer lo que busco con el ejemplo que me enviaste pero me sigue agregando hacía abajo..

Comment: @DarioPerez deberías agregar algo más de información, ¿cómo quieres que se vea? (quizás una imagen o un esquema serían de ayuda) ¿cuáles son los menús que no se ven bien? Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro ya agregué dos items más al menú, los he llamado "Menu2" y "Menú3", pero al pasar el mouse por encima empiezan a titilar. quiero que la parte desplegable de "Donde ir" se conserve, en "Menu2" y "Menú3" no hay parte desplegable o dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que pones en los comentarios sucede porque cuando pasas el ratón por encima (`hover`) cambias el posicionamiento a absoluto. Al poner el posicionamiento absoluto, sacas el elemento del flujo normal de la página y los dos menús resultantes se mueven a la izquierda... provocando que el ratón ya no esté encima del menú abierto y se cierre, quedando de nuevo el ratón encima del menú inicial haciendo que se abra y que cambie a posicionamiento absoluto... que es el parpadeo continuo que ves.

La solución para eso sería quitar el posicionamiento absoluto cuando pasas el ratón por encima (en el CSS es el selector `.menu-municipios:hover`). Eso soluciona el problema del parpadeo, pero crea otro problema: cuando se abre el menú los otros son empujados hacia abajo.

Para solucionar este nuevo problema, indica que la navegación va a tener un `display: flex` y eso hará que los elementos dentro floten hacia arriba (incluso cuando uno está abierto).

Aquí lo puedes ver:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  display: block;
  padding: .2rem 0;
  color: #000;
  font-size: .875rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #050505;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

h4 {
  margin: .5rem 0 .75rem;
  padding-bottom: .5rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: normal;
}

h5 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  font-size: .875rem;
}


nav {
  display: flex;
}

nav::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.menu-municipios {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: .2rem;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.menu-municipios:hover {
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.menu-municipios:hover>li {
  display: block;
}

.menu-municipios:hover>li:first-child {
  border-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: none;
  background-color: #eee;
  box-shadow: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #444;
  cursor: default;
}

.menu-municipios:hover>li:first-child::after {
  content: '\f106';
}

.menu-municipios:hover>li:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 0 .2rem .2rem;
}

.menu-municipios:hover+.temp::after {
  display: block;
}

.menu-municipios>li {
  display: none;
  width: 12rem;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu-municipios>li:first-child {
  display: block;
  padding: .65rem;
  background: #fff;
  color: #0a0a0a;
  font-size: .875rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-municipios>li:first-child::after {
  content: '\f107';
  float: right;
}

.menu-municipios>li:not(:first-child):hover {
  width: calc(960px - 6rem);
  border-right: none;
}

.menu-municipios>li:nth-child(2):hover::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 12rem;
  height: 3rem;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

li h3 {
  width: 12rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding: .65rem .75rem;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-width: 1px 0;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  font-size: .875rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  cursor: default;
}

li:last-child:hover h3 {
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 .2rem;
}

li:hover h3 {
  width: calc(12rem + 1px);
  border-color: #bbb;
}

li:hover div {
  display: block;
}

li div {
  display: none;
  width: calc(960px - 6rem - 12rem);
  padding: 1rem 1.2rem;
  border-left: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-radius: 0 .2rem .2rem 0;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 12rem;
  z-index: 1;
}

.temp {
  display: flex;
  width: 72%;
  border-radius: .2rem;
  float: right;
  font-size: .875rem;
}

.temp::after {
  content: '';
  display: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.temp li {
  padding: .65rem 0;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  clear: both;
}

main p {
  margin: auto;
  color: #555;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

@media (max-width: 60rem) {
  .temp {
    width: 67%;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="menu-municipios">
    <li id>Donde Ir <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></li>
    <li>
      <h3>Naturaleza</h3>
      <div>
        <h4>Naturaleza</h4>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">naturaleza</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">3n</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>arquitectura</h3>
      <div>
        <h4>arquitectura</h4>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>submenu3</h3>
      <div>
        <h4>submenú 3</h4>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>submenu4</h3>
      <div>
        <h4>submenu4</h4>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>submenu5</h3>
      <div>
        <h4>submenu5</h4>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>submenu6</h3>
      <div>
        <h4>submenu6</h4>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>submenu7</h3>
      <div>
        <h4>submenu7</h4>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>submenu8</h3>
      <div>
        <h4>submenu8</h4>
      </div>
    </li>

  </ul>

  <ul class="menu-municipios">
    <li id>menu 2 <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="menu-municipios">
    <li id>menu 3 <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: Me ha servido mucha tu ayuda, pero se me dificulta el tema del posicionamiento de los elementos, bajé la parte desplegable a partir de donde termina el nav, pero el resto de menús(menu2, menu3, menu4,...) se siguen corriendo hacia la derecha cuando despliego el menu "Donde ir".

Comment: @DarioPerez lee mi comentario en tu respuesta. Le echo un ojo en un rato. Saludos